Error with typescript when install dependencies getting a lot of ts errors
I'm trying to run a repository https://github.com/HospitalRun/hospitalrun-frontend.git locally. I followed all the instructions, but when I run npm start, I get a series of TypeScript errors.
Here are some of the errors I'm seeing:

node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts:305:32 - error TS1136: Property assignment expected.

305         [K in keyof t.Aliases]?: VisitNode<S, t.Aliases[K]>;
                                   ~

node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts:305:48 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

305         [K in keyof t.Aliases]?: VisitNode<S, t.Aliases[K]>;
                                                   ~

node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts:305:60 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

305         [K in keyof t.Aliases]?: VisitNode<S, t.Aliases[K]>;
                                                               ~

node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts:308:21 - error TS1005: ']' expected.

308         [K in keyof VirtualTypeAliases]?: VisitNode<S, VirtualTypeAliases[K]>;
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts:308:39 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

308         [K in keyof VirtualTypeAliases]?: VisitNode<S, VirtualTypeAliases[K]>;
                                          ~

node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts:308:40 - error TS1136: Property assignment expected.

308         [K in keyof VirtualTypeAliases]?: VisitNode<S, VirtualTypeAliases[K]>;
                                           ~

node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts:308:41 - error TS1136: Property assignment expected.

308         [K in keyof VirtualTypeAliases]?: VisitNode<S, VirtualTypeAliases[K]>;
                                            ~

node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts:308:74 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

308         [K in keyof VirtualTypeAliases]?: VisitNode<S, VirtualTypeAliases[K]>;
                                                                             ~

node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts:308:77 - error TS1005: ':' expected.

308         [K in keyof VirtualTypeAliases]?: VisitNode<S, VirtualTypeAliases[K]>;
                                                                                ~

node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts:308:78 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

308         [K in keyof VirtualTypeAliases]?: VisitNode<S, VirtualTypeAliases[K]>;
                                                                                 ~

node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts:314:11 - error TS1005: ']' expected.

314         [k: `${string}|${string}`]: VisitNode<S, Node>;
              ~

node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts:314:34 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

314         [k: `${string}|${string}`]: VisitNode<S, Node>;
                                     ~

node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts:314:35 - error TS1136: Property assignment expected.

314         [k: `${string}|${string}`]: VisitNode<S, Node>;
                                      ~

node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts:314:55 - error TS1005: '(' expected.

314         [k: `${string}|${string}`]: VisitNode<S, Node>;
                                                          ~

node_modules/@types/hoist-non-react-statics/node_modules/@types/react/ts5.0/index.d.ts:3340:50 - error TS1110: Type expected.

3340     type OptionalPrefixToken<T extends string> = `${T} ` | "";
                                                      ~~~

node_modules/@types/hoist-non-react-statics/node_modules/@types/react/ts5.0/index.d.ts:3341:51 - error TS1110: Type expected.

3341     type OptionalPostfixToken<T extends string> = ` ${T}` | "";


I'm using Node.js version 12 but have also tried with versions 10 and 14 without success. I suspect the issue might be related to the version of a dependency, but I haven't been able to identify which one.
Can anyone help me diagnose this problem?

This is related to an outdated typescript version.
Try changing the version in package.json:
"typescript": "^4.4.0"

and then run npm install again.
